# cmake - different library for release and debug (zlib/libpng)

Tags: cmake, zlib, libpng

I'm trying to build libpng using cmake. For doing so, an variable for the zlib include directory and zlib library is passed to cmake. Like this:

```
cmake .. -DZLIB_LIBRARY=../../zlib-1.2.8/build/$(Configuration)/zlib.lib -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=../../zlib-1.2.8/
```

which works perfect in release build - but not in debug build. It's almost working - I'm using  $(Configuration) in the path which will use in MS VS either "Debug" or "Release" depending on the Configuration. But mt problem is, that zlib is using different filenames in Debug & Release Mode. Like:

zlib.lib zlib.dll (Release)

zlibd.lib zlibd.dll (Debug)

If I'm using the command above, it will search for the library:

../../zlib-1.2.8/build/Release/zlib.lib (Release -> works)

../../zlib-1.2.8/build/Debug/zlib.lib (Debug -> works not, because the filename is zlibd.lib)

Any ideas how I can accomplish different library names depending on the configuration with cmake (I don't want to change it in the generated VS Project)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `optimized` and `debug` directives like this

```
SET(LIBZ_LIB optimized ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/zlib.lib
             debug ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/zlibd.lib)

target_link_libraries(your-app ... ${LIBZ_LIB}
```

Of course you'll have to fix the path to the library files.

Comment: And here I was going to suggest generator expressions, but look, CMake is smarter than that. more information can be found here: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html

Comment: @IdeaHat That works too but I find this to be cleaner :)